# Plot two implicit surfaces in 3D and highlight their intersection

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, visualization

I want to plot the two surfaces which are defined in $ \mathbb{ R }^3 \ni ( x, y, z ) $ via the  equations $ 0 = y^2 - x*(x^2 + 1) $ and $ 0 = z^2 - y*(y^2 + 1) $, respectively.
Moreover, I want also to highlight the intersection curve of these surfaces.

Any tool is ok for me, but I know that sage has some functions for plotting implicit functions in 3d:
The commands

```
var('x, y, z') 
s1 = implicit_plot3d(0 == y^2 - x*(x^2 + 1), (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3), (z,-3,3))
s2 = implicit_plot3d(0 == z^2 - y*(y^2 + 1), (x,-3,3), (y,-3,3), (z,-3,3))
plot(s1 + s2)
```

plot both surfaces.
But I would like to highlight the intersection curve or at least change the transparency-level of the surfaces (changing the alpha-values seems not to do anything)

A bonus would also be if there were a way to directly plot the intersection of these surfaces.

Does anybody know a tool to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]      
        
Blue curve is the intersection of the two surfaces $ 0 = y^2 - x(x^2 + 1) $ and $ 0 = z^2 - y(y^2 + 1) $.

The 3D plots were generated with Mathematica, as documented [here.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html)

Comment: This is exaclty what I want. Unfortunately, the free version of mathematica on https://www.wolframalpha.com/ seems not to do that. Or am I mistaking?

Comment: I'm afraid this is beyond the capabilities of wolfram alpha; I would be happy to supply you with any image you like though, you can email me your parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your offer. I appreciate it. But this won't be the last plot I will need. Anyway, I think we have mathematica on the computers in the university. So there will always be this solution. But a solution which runs on my home pc would be better. This is the only reason why I don't click on 'accept as an answer'.

Comment: I found https://www.wolframcloud.com. There I could do the plot using mathematica for free. Thank you very much.